# Present View with Navigation intact : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification

My app has a Tinder-like functionality where I have to show a view on receiving a notification. Problem is that I'm not being able to keep the navigation hierarchy intact. My flow right now is
view1 -> Navigation controller -> view 2 -> tab bar controller -> view3, view,4 view 5...view 5-> view6 -> view 7. 
I want to present a view, View 8. which has two buttons ignore and accept. Accept should present view 6 and ignore should present view 5. View5 is at index 2 of the tab bar controller. 
I have achieved this by regular segues but the navigation bar disappears. 
Here is my code in app delegate to present View 8 upon receiving a notification

```
if notifType == Const.NOTIF_MATCH_FOUND
            {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "in-tune-Main", bundle: nil)
                let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("matchVC") as? matchVC
                self.window?.rootViewController = destinationController
            }
```

This takes it to view8, and loads view 6 or 5 on clicking ignore or accept but the navigation disappears. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Another way I can achieve this is push the desired view controller with the navigation stack intact upon pressing Accept or Ignore. Looking to achieve this now

Comment: So I embedded a navigation controller before view 1 and removed the one after it. That solved the problem of presenting view 8. Now i'm trying to present the index[2] of tabBarControler in the accept button action of view8.